# SPO 2013 - How to open Links List items (websites) in a new window/tab when clicking with the left mouse button?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, links-list

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013.

In our intranet we have the OOTB Links List on a page so users can add links to important external websites in it. As a default those links are just opening in the current window and effectively taking the user out of the intranet site.

We would like to have the links open in a new tab when clicking with the left mouse button. How can this be done? I thought of making a .js Javascript file and link it using the Link List's "JS-Link" option in the toolbox but as I don't know any Javascript I can't write it myself.

I have searched the internet high and low, tried different scripts and solutions but just can't seem to get it working right. Feels like this kind of this should be a default option in Sharepoint.

**** EDIT/SOLUTION ****

I managed to figure it out right after I made this question. I have one script that didn't work in my .js file and I just blindly edited it to try one more desperate thing and it worked!

So if anyone else wants to know, the answer is to make a filenamehere.js and include the following script inside it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").removeAttr('onclick').attr("target","_blank");
   });
```

After that, save the script file in your Site Collection SiteAssets folder and put "~sitecollection/SiteAssets/filenamehere.js" in your JS-Link option in the Web Part settings/toolbox. :-)

**EDIT 2:** I noticed that somehow the script is now applied to the global site navigation links too even when I have applied the script on in the Web Part JS-Link option. If anyone knows how to fix this, that would be more than awesome! :-)

Comment: Where can I get the WebPartWPQ Number following for the List that I need it?
A List/LIbrary has no WebPart Setting to point to the Javascript? Help please.

Comment: Using browser's developer tools (F12) you can inspect any elements and their tags/attributes. Also I'm not being mean but you should not use answers to ask another question. Better way is to use the comments or preferably ask/create a new question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem and just wanted to share the answer with anyone who might be searching for the same thing. So I just studied jQuery a bit to see how it works and the solution was simple, just needed to make a more specified target for the script rather than just a which selects all links.

What I did was select all links in the specified List (WPQ#). Here's an example if your list is named "WebPartWPQ1":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#WebPartWPQ1 a" ).attr("target","_blank");
   });
```

I hope this helps anyone who has the same need to open Links List items in a new tab! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to add the $("#WebPart...") line for each webpart you want you to take effect if you want to leave the top nav bar links alone.