# How to open up View Item from task list in SPO in a new tab

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I am working with SPOnline Task list. Users click on View Item for a given task to go to the display form which by default opens in same window. Is there a way to open it up in a separate tab? Probably JS or JQ, if anyone has tried, please assisy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a middle click in your mouse to open a new tab. And here are some scripts you can have a try if you can add content editor to your page.

[SPO 2013 - How to open Links List items (websites) in a new window/tab when clicking with the left mouse button?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116482/spo-2013-how-to-open-links-list-items-websites-in-a-new-window-tab-when-clic)

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Open-SharePoint-Links-into-76550ff1/view/Discussions#content

Comment: Well but I am only looking to open View Item link in a new tab on the task list page. Is that possible?